# replace value of element by xquery

Tags: xml, xslt, xquery

I found this existing post on replacing the value of a given element, but I need to go further with my requirment in that I need to replace the first character with another.
This is the post I found: **change value of element by xquery**

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<category>
    <catid>1</catid>
    <cattext>sport</cattext>
</category>
```

Using this Xquery:

```
declare namespace local = "http://example.org";
declare function local:copy-replace($element as element()) {
  if ($element/self::cattext)
  then <cattext>art</cattext>
  else element {node-name($element)}
               {$element/@*,
                for $child in $element/node()
                return if ($child instance of element())
                       then local:copy-replace($child)
                       else $child
               }
};
local:copy-replace(/*)
```

Gives this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<category>
    <catid>1</catid>
    <cattext>art</cattext>
</category>
```

My knowledge of Xquery is only just starting grow. How do I change the above Xquery to only change the first character so that I get the below output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<category>
    <catid>1</catid>
    <cattext>9port</cattext>
</category>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use the [substring()](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-substring) function**:

```
declare namespace local = "http://example.org";
declare function local:copy-replace($element as element()) {
  if ($element/self::cattext)
  then <cattext>9{substring($element,2)}</cattext>
  else element {node-name($element)}
               {$element/@*,
                for $child in $element/node()
                return if ($child instance of element())
                       then local:copy-replace($child)
                       else $child
               }
};
local:copy-replace(/*)
```

**When this query is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<category>
    <catid>1</catid>
    <cattext>sport</cattext>
</category>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<category>
    <catid>1</catid>
    <cattext>9port</cattext>
</category>
```

**The same transformation is much easier to do with XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="cattext/text()">
  <xsl:text>9</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="substring(., 2)"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), again the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<category>
   <catid>1</catid>
   <cattext>9port</cattext>
</category>
```

Comment: Thank you Dimitre. Now if I could trouble you a bit more, what would an XSLT look like to perform the same thing.

Comment: @TonyJ: I have added to this answer an XSLT transformation that produces the same result. Do note how much easier it is to express transformations with XSLT. The explicit resursion is gone -- it isn't necessary.

Comment: Definitly easier to read and enhance if required with XSLT transformation. Thank you again Dimitre.