# XQuery - replace empty element with a text value (on output to HTML)

Tags: xquery, xquery-3.0

I have nodes like these across a collection of xml:tei documents:

```
[...]
<persName  nymRef="#Guilhem_Canast-Brus_MSP-AU" ana="#pAdo #pAud" role="par">Willelmum de Canast-Brus</persName>
<persName  nymRef="#Guilhem_Canast-Brus_MSP-AU" ana="#pAdo #pAud #pPax" role="par">Willelmum de Canast-Brus</persName>
<persName  nymRef="#Guilhem_Canast-Brus_MSP-AU" role="own">Willelmi de Canast-Brus</persName>
<persName  nymRef="#Guilhem_Canast-Brus_MSP-AU" ana="#pAdo" role="par">W<supplied reason="expname">illelmum</supplied> de Canast</persName>
<persName  nymRef="#Guilhem_Canast-Brus_MSP-AU" role="own">Willelmi<lb break="y" n="20"/>de Canast Brus</persName>
<persName  nymRef="#Guilhem_Canast-Brus_MSP-AU" ana="#pAdo #pAud #pPax" role="par">Willelmum de<lb break="y" n="22"/>Canast</persName>
<persName  nymRef="#Guilhem_Canast-Brus_MSP-AU" ana="#pAdo" role="par">Willelmum de Canast Brus</persName>
<persName  nymRef="#Guilhem_Canast-Brus_MSP-AU" role="own">Willelmi de Canast-Brus</persName>
<persName  nymRef="#Guilhem_Canast-Brus_MSP-AU" ana="#pAud #pAdo" role="par">W<supplied reason="expname">illelmum</supplied> de Canast</persName>
<persName  nymRef="#Guilhem_Canast-Brus_MSP-AU" ana="#nAdo" role="par">W<supplied reason="expname">illelmum</supplied> de Canast Bru</persName>
[...]
```

The following query in XQuery 3.1:

```
let $a := 
  <div>
   {let $x := functx:remove-elements-deep(collection($coll)//tei:persName[@nymRef="#Guilhem_Canast-Brus_MSP-AU"][text()],("supplied","corr","del"))
    for $y in $x
    let $z := normalize-space(string-join(replace($y,",","")))
      group by $z
      order by $z ascending
      return  <span>
              {$z}
              </span>
}</div>
return $a
```

Returns the following HTML with a number of descendant nodes (ie. `supplied`, `corr`) removed using `functx:remove-elements-deep`:

```
<div>
  <span>R de Canast</span>
  <span>W</span>
  <span>W Bru</span>
  <span>W Bru de Canast</span>
  <span>W Canast Bru</span>
  <span>W de Canast</span>
  <span>W de Canast Bru</span>
  <span>W de Canast Brus</span>
  <span>W de Canast qui dicitur Lo Brus</span>
  <span>W de Canast- Bru</span>
  <span>W de Canast-Bru</span>
  <span>W de Canast-Brus</span>
  <span>W de CanastBru</span>
  <span>W de CanastBrus</span>
  <span>Willelmi</span>
  <span>Willelmi Canast-Bru</span>
  <span>Willelmi de Canast</span>
  <span>Willelmi de Canast Bru</span>
  <span>Willelmi de Canast Brus</span>
  <span>Willelmi de Canast iunioris</span>
  <span>Willelmi de Canast qui dicitur Brus</span>
  <span>Willelmi de Canast-Brus</span>
  <span>Willelmi de CanastBru</span>
  <span>Willelmi de Canastle Bru</span>
  <span>Willelmide Canast Brus</span>
  <span>Willelmide Canast-Brus</span>
  <span>Willelmo de Canast</span>
  <span>Willelmum de Canast</span>
  <span>Willelmum de Canast Brus</span>
  <span>Willelmum de Canast-Brus</span>
  <span>Willelmum deCanast</span>
  <span>Willelmus de Canast</span>
</div>
```

However, there are several (empty) elements that I would like to replace with string. For example replace `lb[@break="y"]` with a " ", and `gap` with "[ ]", like in this example:

```
<persName  nymRef="#Guilhem_Canast-Brus_MSP-AU" role="own">Willelmi<lb break="y" n="20"/>de Canast Brus</persName>
```

I was looking at [`functx:replace-element-values`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_replace-element-values.html) but I could not identify how to integrate it.

Many thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Are these empty elements all children of the `persName` elements or can they be as descendants at nested levels?

Comment: There is a possibility in some cases where they are descendants of `persName`, not just direct children...

Comment: Will it suffice to pass in the elements names like `lb` or `gap` and the corresponding replacements or do you need to check attributes like `@break = 'y'` or other conditions as well?

Comment: It will have to check an attribute at times. I've posted below a hack that works, but is not really maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

Using [replace value of element by xquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11769922/replace-value-of-element-by-xquery), I managed to come up with a hack.

```
declare namespace local = "http://example.org";

declare function local:copy-replace($element as element()) {
  if ($element/self::lb[@break eq "y"])
  then " "
  else if ($element/self::gap)
  then "[  ]"
  else element {node-name($element)}
           {$element/@*,
            for $child in $element/node()
            return if ($child instance of element())
                   then local:copy-replace($child)
                   else $child
           }
   };

   local:copy-replace(<persName  nymRef="#Guilhem_Canast-Brus_MSP-AU" role="own">Willelmi<lb break="y" n="20"/>de Can<gap/>t Brus</persName>)
```

Returns:

```
<persName nymRef="#Guilhem_Canast-Brus_MSP-AU" role="own">Willelmi de Can[  ]t Brus</persName>
```

Which I can then continue processing as above.